# Dockerfile CMD for taking bash commands from host

Tags: bash, docker

I've created a dockerfile with various compile and build tools. The goal of the dockerimage is to standardize our development tools, and make it easy and consistent for developing.

Everything is installed.

What I am stuck on, is how to make the docker container keep running, and be able to have a bash shell to that container so that I can run, for example, `make` etc. ?

If I use  `ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash` my container exits immediately. How to keep the container running?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the command at run time. You run your Docker container in interatice mode (-i) and set the command to "/bin/bash":

```
docker run -it myDockerImage myCommandToExecuteInteractively
```

For instance:

```
docker run -it myDocker /bin/bash
```

Here is a real life example:

a) Pulling the most basic image

```
docker pull debian:jessie-slim
```

b) Let's have a bash there:

```
docker run -it debian:jessie-slim /bin/bash
```

c) Enjoy:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A docker container will run as long as the CMD/Entrypoint from your Dockerfile takes.

You can run your Docker container in interactive mode using switch `i`

```
sudo docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash <imagename>
```

**Example** : `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash ubuntu:14.04`
This will start an interactive shell in your container. Your container will exit as soon as you exit that shell.